# Invalid prop `selectRow` of type `string` supplied to `BootstrapTable`, expected `object`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table, and I am passing proper column and data to the table and it working fine with me.

But I am get in the console warning as

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `selectRow` of type `string` supplied to `BootstrapTable`, expected `object`.
```

Here is my Code:

```
<Table columns={columns} data={data}
    actions={action} cellEdit={{ mode: 'click' }} />
```

[image: b]

Trying to remove to the warning from browser console.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use `BootstrapTable` anywhere else in the code? the error suggest that you've provided attribute `selectRow` somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Yes it needed **selectRow** as props

```
const selectRow = {
      style: { background: '#f2f2f2' }
    }

<Table columns={columns} data={data} selectRow={selectRow}
    actions={action} cellEdit={{ mode: 'click' }} />
```